# POSTGRESQL: 1 query from 6 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to produce 1 query from 6 tables which is suppose to display the title, the production year and the total number of oscars it has won across all categories. I was trying to join them all before, but in some categories (e.g. actor_award, there is no 'Oscar' entry at all and in other tables like crew_award 'Oscar' is entered 7 times) The code I have produced doesn't work, but I think it works as pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve. Can anyone help me out?

```
SELECT movie.title, movie.production_year, COUNT(actor+crew+movie+writer+director)
WHERE 

(SELECT * FROM actor_award WHERE actor_award.title = 'Titanic' AND 
(actor_award.result = 'won' or actor_award.result = 'Won') 
AND actor_award.award_name = 'Oscar') AS actor AND


(SELECT * FROM crew_award WHERE crew_award.title = 'Titanic' AND 
(crew_award.result = 'won' or crew_award.result = 'Won') 
AND crew_award.award_name = 'Oscar') AS crew AND

(SELECT * FROM movie_award WHERE movie_award.title = 'Titanic' AND 
(movie_award.result = 'won' or movie_award.result = 'Won') 
AND movie_award.award_name = 'Oscar') AS movie AND

(SELECT * FROM writer_award WHERE writer_award.title = 'Titanic' AND 
(writer_award.result = 'won' or writer_award.result = 'Won') 
AND writer_award.award_name = 'Oscar') AS writer AND

(SELECT * FROM director_award WHERE director_award.title = 'Titanic' AND 
(director_award.result = 'won' or director_award.result = 'Won') 
AND director_award.award_name = 'Oscar') AS director AND

movie.title = 'titanic' AND
movie.production_year = '1997'

GROUP BY movie.title, movie.production_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to access results for different tables [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) (WITH queries) can produce very readable queries.

```
WITH actors_awards as (
    SELECT count(*) as n_awards FROM actor_award
    WHERE actor_award.title = 'Titanic'
          AND (actor_award.result = 'won' or actor_award.result = 'Won')
          AND actor_award.award_name = 'Oscar'
),
crew_awards as (
    SELECT count(*) as n_awards FROM crew_award
    WHERE crew_award.title = 'Titanic'
          AND (crew_award.result = 'won' or crew_award.result = 'Won')
          AND crew_award.award_name = 'Oscar'
),
movie_awards as (
    SELECT count(*) as n_awards FROM movie_award
    WHERE movie_award.title = 'Titanic'
          AND (movie_award.result = 'won' or movie_award.result = 'Won')
          AND movie_award.award_name = 'Oscar'
),
writer_awards as (
    SELECT count(*) as n_awards FROM writer_award
    WHERE writer_award.title = 'Titanic'
          AND (writer_award.result = 'won' or writer_award.result = 'Won')
          AND writer_award.award_name = 'Oscar'
),
director_awards as (
    SELECT count(*) as n_awards FROM director_award
           WHERE director_award.title = 'Titanic'
           AND (director_award.result = 'won' or director_award.result = 'Won')
           AND director_award.award_name = 'Oscar'
)

SELECT 'titanic' as title, 
       '1997' as production_year,
       (actor_awards.n_awards + crew_awards.n_awards + movie_awards.n_awards + writer_awards.n_awards + director_awards.n_awards) as n_awards
FROM actor_awards, crew_awards, movie_awards, writer_awards, director_awards;
```

Take into account that i doesn't run the query so it could have spelling errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking into WITH right now

Comment: Or a simple subquery-in-`FROM`, which [often performs much better in PostgreSQL](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/)

Comment: Craig in this case as the question seems to be 'homework' i found cte more 'formative' and 'readable', but thanks for the comment i usually read 2ndquadrant blog.

Comment: I cannot get this to run the query either Francisco, but the theory seems correct. The error i receive is "missing FROM-clause entry for table "actors_awards", but the FROM is not missing.

Comment: i might post your solution again to see if anyone can help identify the error, i really want to get this done! is that alright?

Comment: There's also a redundant closing bracket in the first CTE. Really, sir, wouldn't it have been easier to spot the mistakes if you had formatted your query in a more readable manner from the beginning?

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for the advise. I re-formated it and fixed the typo